# How to echo money formated with {function ...}{/function} in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

How to echo money formated  with {function name="money_fomart" value=$money}{/function} in smarty?

I have returned money in money_fomart, but the tag does not show it?

Sorry, i may not describe clearly.  i want to define the function 'money_fomart' in common.php, and call it to format a value in smarty tpl, can i ?

Comment: Let's see your function definition in more detail, as well as how you're calling this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check this: [Extending Smarty With Plugins](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins)

Comment: $smarty->registerPlugin("function","money_fomart", "print_money_fomart");    http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl     got it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
{function name=money_fomart}
<--{$data*2}-->
{/function}


{call name=money_fomart data=100}
```

Isn't it?

Comment: Thank you! But i mean call a function 'money_fomart' in my common.php to format the $money, not define the function in smarty tpl

Comment: maybe you will send to template varibale, after formarting?

Answer (score 0):

...but you have an empty function definition.

If all you want to know how to call your newly created function then do it like this: `{money_format}`

By the way, it's all well written in the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl).

Comment: Thank you Janis, how can i define the function 'money_fomart' in common.php, and call it to format a value in smarty tpl?

Comment: There are [different types of plugins](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl). I suspect that you just need a [modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl). To create it, create a file named modifier.money_format.php in your plugins dir (and read the docs so you know what function to write in there). Afterwards you can call it in template like this: `$var|money_format`. To use that function in php script, just insert this line: `require_once(SMARTY_PLUGINS_DIR . 'modifier.money_format.php');`

Comment: Great, thank you. if i add money_fomart in my func.php, and register it, $smarty->registerPlugin("modifier","money_fomart", "money_fomart"); if this has the same effect, it will be more convenient